# Multiple dropdown values from form to mysql in Php

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am creating a form where one part users need to fill in openinghours. The form is created dynamicly with a switch case (for radio, tekst, etc) and an array that contains the actual data for the form.

This is how the output looks like right now for the openingshours

http://jsfiddle.net/rxwuc/

its basicly monday till sunday, before noon and past noon.

This is how the mysql table looks like at the moment (could be changed but prefer to have not too many records needed just for this...)

```
RAF_COM_OPUREN_ID int(11)   Nee Geen AUTO_INCREMENT     Meer   Bekijk unieke waarden 
RAF_COM_OPUREN_FK_ID int(11)     
RAF_COM_OPUREN_DATE_ID enum('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')    
RAF_COM_OPUREN_VMVAN varchar(5)    
RAF_COM_OPUREN_VMTOT varchar(5)       
RAF_COM_OPUREN_NMVAN varchar(5)      
RAF_COM_OPUREN_NMTOT varchar(5)
```

Can anyone help me on how to get these values into the tables? I do understand php but I'm not sure on the optimal way to do this.

Any tips much appreciated.

Comment: I have edited the php so the generated html creates a unique "name" for every dropdown. I know how to get everything into the database except for the day, wich has to be a number 1 to 7 for the days of the week. No idea how I could post the day to the database...

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to change your table to:

```
id int(11)
day var_char(16) -> store Maandag, Dinsdag, Woensdag...
shift var_char(16) -> store before / after
time varchar(5) -> store timing
```

PHP code to form the array:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name"); 
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // store into array grouped by day & type
    $open_time[ $data['day'] ][ $data['type'] ][] = $data['time']; 
}
```

Let me know if you need help to transform this array into html.

Comment: I am getting it wrong or is this to get the data out of the DB? First I need to get it inserted into the DB. And I would prefer not to store the actual name of the days as it will need to be multi-language. So 1 would be maandag or monday in whatever language needed. The main problem why I don't know how to solve this is because i don't know where to get the day from. 

I can get all the values from the dropdown and post them but then I only have the values without the according day...

Comment: Sorry that I read your question wrongly. Easiest is to manually key in.

Comment: No problem! Didn't mean it offensive in any way. What do you mean by keying in manually?